# How to draw smooth trend line with matplotlib in Python with Date in X axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, databricks

I have to generate analysis of flight reports. In the chart I'm trying to draw, each point is corresponding to one flight with the Date in X-axis. So, It is possible to have several points for the same X.

Each point represent the aircraft speed at a specific moment in the flight. The pilot did good if the value (IAS in knots) is in the range 80-95. So, I want to show if the pilot is getting better by a running median on 8 values. But, sometime there are multiple flights on the same day so it creates "vertical lines" in the trendline.

I'm using Python on Databricks.

There is my dataset:
[image]

And there is the plot:
[image]

What is the best way to draw a smooth trend line dealing with Date as X-axis and the multiple points on same X ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit vague. Could you indicate what would qualify as a trendline for you? The data shows very high scatter... are you looking for a trend in daily median values? Running median? Mean?

Comment: @VBB, each point represent the aircraft speed at a specific moment in the flight. The pilot did good if the value (IAS in knots) is in the range 80-95. So, I want to show if the pilot is getting better by a running median on 8 values. But, sometime there are multiple flights on the same day so it creates "vertical lines" in the trendline.

Comment: So do you want to draw a trendline through all points? Or a trendline through each day? Or through 8 points (that you mentioned)? For me it looks more like you are looking for something like [`pandas.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), which resamples datetime indexes so that you have one data point for each day / month / second etc. Alternatively you could build running means.